# Can anyone tell me why this haml code does not displays anything

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

```
- form_tag sign_in_users_path do 
  - if @user.errors.any? 
    %div#error_explanation
  %h2= pluralize(@user.errors.count, "error") 
  %ul
    - @user.errors.full_messages do |msg|
  %li= msg

  = label_tag :login
  = text_field_tag :login
  = label_tag :password
  = password_field_tag :password

  %div.form_actions
    = submit_tag
```

I am trying to create a login form in haml i am totally new to it. I am able to display all
other things except this block.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change `- form_tag sign_in_users_path do` to `= form_tag sign_in_users_path do`.

Answer (score 1):

`-` lets you execute some code in haml which wont get printed. 
`=` prints the string value of the code you execute. Since you want to add a `<form>` tag here (by calling the `form_tag` helper) you want to user `=` instead of `-`.